# Adding of new matter in Patent 8,088,480

Tags: prior-art, patent-infringement, us8088480

Patent [US8088480](http://www.google.com/patents/US8088480) - Spend 10 years in the patent office and the file wrapper is really long. It looks like they have started infringement cases with 2 other companies. I am looking for a little help with New matter and Prior Art.

Questions;
1. Has any one seen or had cases with adding new matter incorrectly they added in new matter about 6 years into the case to over come Prior Art.
2. Help with Prior Art.

Comment: It is a long file wrapper. Could you be clear about what papers submitted on what date may have contained new matter? Was it questioned by the examiner at the time?

Comment: Infringement suits are serious things and you seem well represented. I think you should probably only talk to your attorney about this. One thing I can suggest is a site called Article One that allows people to put up cash bounties for prior art. New matter is not allowed so I assume the othe side will argue that what your pleading calls new matter is not actually new matter.

Comment: Thanks George - I was more looking for Pior Art help so I can check out Article One just looked like this might be the place to get more help. Yes, It is a Serious thing.. Thanks for the Lead.